# Porque variable pierde valor fuera del web service?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Buen dia mi problema es el sigueinte estoy haciendo una consulta en mi base de datos oracle la cueal me devuelve un resultado una cadena de dos columnas la cual yo necesito la segunda para consumir un web service tuve problemas para consumir este ws hasta que cree una funcion solo para el donde mando el valor mencionado, el problema es que declaro una array para ingresar los dos valores comentados mas un tercer que es parte de la respuesta del webservice, estos se genera y se visualizan por medio del console.log(var1, var2, var3), pero al momento de asignarlos al array estos dejan de tener valor
adjunto mi codigo

````
    var o = new Array(); // empty Object
    
    let conn

    try {
        conn = await oracledb.getConnection(config)

        result = await conn.execute(
            "select campo, campo|| numerofrom \n" +
            "USUARIO.TABLA\n" +
            "where CAMPO is null"
        )
            
             atc(result.rows).then(val =>  o.push(val));  
            
         
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Ouch!', err)
    } finally {
        if (conn) { // conn assignment worked, need to close
            await conn.close()
        }
    }

return o;   


}


async function atc(cont){


   
    var lista = new Array();

    
    for (let index = 0; index < cont.length; index++) {
        var data = JSON.stringify({
            "VAR": cont[index][1]
        });
    
        var config = {
            method: 'post',
            url: 'URL',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Basic ',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Cookie': '__cf_bm=wgST39DCVUoSqJcRoLHY4daKWkaFW.pD2i2KsNu5Kkk-1648309458-0-AbjRC3mQhKsPo+1Tdy22ZQF1G+PlBTWihZLT3qhejFuXNT2XnZSqPUbArV/14eA1rDlO1RFzSQJGbhj3dsW7a2M='
            },
            data: data
        };
    
        axios(config)
            .then(function (response) {

                if(response.data.codigo == 1){
                    
                   
                    lista.push(cont[index][0], cont[index][1], response.data.operacion.val[0].val);
                    
                    console.log(cont[index][0], cont[index][1], response.data.operacion.val[0].val)
                    
                }
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        
        
    }
    
    
    console.log(lista);
    
        return lista;

}

getEmployee().then(val => console.log(val));```
````

Comment: Porque no estás manejando correctamente la asincronía. Los datos de `lista` sólo existen dentro de la función `then`.

Comment: Y no uses new array. Solo declara let miArray = []

Comment: @MauricioContreras y cual seria la forma correcta de aplicarla ?